# Elasticsearch is running on https instead of http. How to fix this issue?

Tags: elasticsearch

The elastic search is running in https server instead of http and I am getting error as http client did not trust this server's certificate, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/127.0.0.1:9200, remoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:58238}

Answer (score 3):

I do not recommend this but you can disable the default HTTP TLS settings by changing `xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled = false` in the configuration file `elasticsearch.yml`

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-settings.html